# shown Custom Error Page instead of my Images

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, custom-error-pages

After I Created Custom Error Page in my Project
The custom error page is shown instead of all images that can not be found in Project.

for example: I have not this route "localhost:44389/help/1" in my project and when I Address it in browser custom error page is shown, up to here  all things is right and also this source of data

```
<object class="price-popup__contact-info__row__icon" data="~/Landing/images/services/phone-icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

is not in my root and it shown custom error page instead of not showing this image.

if some of my code is need I will send.

It's my startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Errors/{0}");
        }            
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
```

how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `The custom error page is shown instead of all images that can not be found in Project.` Please clarify more about the issue, so that we can understand and help troubleshoot it better.

Comment: You could add service, which would inspect HTTP status code and inject custom HTML into a response.

Comment: @FeiHan I edited my post and tried to explaine more. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom middleware to do that, you just need to inspect HTTP code to see if there were an error:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.Use(async (context, nextAction) => 
    {
        if(context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Sorry, it looks like we don't have a picture you requested");
            return;
        }
        await nextAction();
    }
    // rest of your services...
}
```

See for reference: [Write custom ASP.NET Core middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

Each of these "Use" methods define a middleware handler in your pipeline;

```cs
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseMvc(...);
```

If your case, `UseStaticFiles()` will cause all exact matches to content in your "wwwroot" folder to be returned. But it will do nothing if no file is found, even if the parent folder exists. In which case your other middleware will be given the chance to handle the request.

You could add another middleware, after static files, that treats all requests for your images folder as errors.

```cs
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.Map("/images", b => {
            // no static file matched this request, TODO provide a specific custom error page or image.
        });
        app.UseRouting();
        ...
```